# Why does google places' location object use methods to return longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm making an app that uses Google's Places API. After querying, you get a `places` object. `places.geometry.location` contains the longitude and latitude of the place. You can see them each stored there under random variable names, like `$a` and `yY`, for example.

The official way to access these values is through `location.lat()` and `location.lng()`. I'm curious as to why they use methods, rather than fixed values. Additionally, do they use random variable names to keep people from accessing them directly?

Comment: presumably, the random names are probably due to Javascript minimization (Closure Compiler)

Comment: I'm moving to re-open this question. While it isn't necessarily addressing a specific issue that the OP is running into, it is an important question about code design and has a concrete answer. I've wondered about this in the past (with maps and other JS apis) and the fact that so many major JS libraries use methods in cases that seem inappropriate may lead programmers into concluding that there is some fundamental programmatic reason to avoid properties in favor of methods... if it's just to avoid issues when obfuscating/minifying it's important to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google code is [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) / minimized and uses short variable names that can change from one day to another.

So that's why you use methods to retrieve their values.

Comment: Why change from one day to another?

Comment: If they change something (update, bug fix, etc) they will minimize the code again and those variables will most probably get other aliases